# Override function in craftyjs

Tags: javascript, function, overriding, craftyjs

I'm new to JS and trying to override a function in Craftyjs, here is my code:

```
    Crafty.c('TestA', {
        init: function() {                
            Crafty.addEvent(this, Crafty.stage.elem, "mousedown", this._e_clickListener);
        },
        _e_clickListener: function(e){
            this.foo();
        },
        foo: function() {
            console.log('call A foo');
        }
    });

    Crafty.c('TestB', {
        init: function() {
            this.requires('TestA');                
        },
        foo: function(){
            console.log('call B foo');
        }
    });

    Crafty.e('TestB');
```

The result when i click on the canvas is:

```
    call A foo
```

Is there anyway to turn it into 'call B foo' instead?
Thanks.

Comment: Just remember Crafty is built on [ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system) pattern and consider [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with *CraftyJS* and the documentation could use a little *TLC* - unless I've missed something it looks as if calling `requires` is  simply amalgamating ***everying*** into a single object - last-in takes precedence.  No inheritance so no superclass - just one flat object.

Perhaps there's a better way but I could only get it to *"override"* the function by simply assigning it inside the `init` function ***after*** you've imported your required components.

```js
Crafty.c('TestB', {
    init: function() {
        this.requires('TestA');
        this.foo = function(){
            console.log('call B foo');
        }
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dgvHK/)

Comment: Yup, when a component is added to an entity, it simply blindly copies all the defined properties and components onto the entity's object.  It's probably best practice to *not* overwrite existing methods, but if you have to, you need to do it after you attach that component.